# Activate Pre-load onclick from a different page

Tags: javascript

I have some links at the bottom of my webpage:

http://puu.sh/aQHbz/911cfd78b8.png

I want each one of the floor links to display the corresponding floor on a separate page:

http://puu.sh/aQHpR/dd5625150e.jpg

Basically, I want each link to preload the picture so that when you click on the floor 2 link for example, the 2nd floor map is already loaded on the next screen.

I don't know if I can do this only using JavaScript and HTML. Any help is appreciated. Thank you. Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
function showstuff(boxid){
document.getElementById(boxid).style.display='';

}

function hidestuff(boxid){
document.getElementById(boxid).style.display='none';

}


function pic(DivID,ImageName)
{
document.getElementById(DivID).innerHTML="<img src=/studentcenter/images  /"+ImageName+">";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show the images in new window. Then If the window already opened you can access it and change its href.

Here is the html part

```
<img src="http://puu.sh/aQHbz/911cfd78b8.png" onclick = "newImage(this.src)"/>

<img src="http://puu.sh/aQHpR/dd5625150e.jpg" onclick = "newImage(this.src)"/>
```

Here is the javascript part.

```
var win = false; //window exist variable

function newImage(e){
    if(win.open){
        win.focus() //Focus to map window
        win.location.href=e; //Change to new image
    }else{
        win = open(e, 'example', 'width=300,height=300'); //Open a new window with the image url
    }
}
```

You can see the solution on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmtLm2eo/).

You must put javascript part to head or before your images.